# TV that behaves more like a monitor

Tags: television

Need TVs which behave more like a monitor (as below).

Only 4K mainstream priced TVs, 40-60 inches, supporting RGB 4K60 over HDMI 2.0 ports are considered.

40 inch+ monitors are very expensive, 40 inch+ TVs are very cheap.

(1) Monitors will turns on/off automatically (unless it is "full off") when the input signal is on/off, but most TV doesn't have this feature, they will just display a no signal message when the input HDMI signal is off.

(2) Monitors will switch to another HDMI signal that is on automatically when the current displayed HDMI signal is off

(3) Better to be non-android TV which is to slow to turn on, but since most 4K TVs are android based, the more realizable goal is the TV have a standby mode and the time from active to standby and from standby to active is as fast as possibile (for comparison, for phone and tablet this is less than 0.5 seconds, the fastest TV I'v used need 6~10 seconds)

(4) Monitor will display the image when on, but for most TVs the default scene is the home page and you need operate the remote to display some HDMI signal. Besides for TVs switching between HDMI signals need multiple remote button clicks. Monitors can also remember the HDMI channel displayed last time and you don't need to swtich channel each time.

Comment: What kind of budget do you have? What is the use case for this monitor? There is a chance we could pin down a monitor without your budget that matches your specs. Trying to find a TV with the exact specifications above is going to be extremely difficult b/c it is uncommon un-quantitative criteria. If you're planning on using this system for gaming I would highly advise against it.

Comment: @BennettYeo Need 40inch+ monitor for general application with multiple HDMI sources, but not those expensive niche ones.

Comment: Most monitors come with 2 HDMI inputs what would your upper $ limit be? Also I would highly suggest display port over HDMI.

Comment: @BennettYeo Main point of the question is not HDMI, but other factors. Why do you suggest DP? DP is general purpose link like USB3, HDMI is specially designed for video, e.g. HDMI can tranfer 4K60 for meters with very low cable cost.

Comment: Usually I recommend DP for future proofing bandwidth, daisy chaining monitors. If you've already researched and determined HDMI to work best for your use case that should work fine. I can't, however, recommend you a concrete product unless you give me your *price limit* as only you best know what "cheap" or "expensive" means for you.

Comment: @BennettYeo There is no exact price limit. By cheap I mean main stream priced, not those high end products. "future proofing bandwidth, daisy chaining monitors" HDMI support 4K144 too that is the final spec for screen(higher spec won't benefit human much unless they evolved too). Only VR need 16K144 @ short range.

Comment: Not enough attention, so I added a bounty.